# Get id from other table then insert into table. I want to click the button then answer current question

Tags: javascript, php, sql

```
<?php require_once('connection.php');  
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{  
    $answ = $_POST['answ'];      
    $email = $_SESSION['email']; 


    $insert = "INSERT INTO answerList (answ,queID,email) SELECT questionList.queID FROM questionList   " ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
 
    if (!$result) {
        echo "<script>alert('ERROR !!!!! '); location='faq.php';</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Successful Post'); location='faq.php'; </script>";
    }
    


}
?>
```

I have 3 table
table 1: users(email, password)
table 2: question(questionID, questionContent, email)
table 3: answer(answerID, answerContent, questionID, email)

how can i connect questionID into table 3?
i already do the login and add question sql . but how can i add the answer to current question with logged email?

[a table have question. and each question have answer button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nugYn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<input type='hidden' name='questionId' value='<?php echo $value>'>`

For each question you'll have to set `$value` to the questionID.

When the answer is submited you'll do:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{  
    $answ = $_POST['answ'];      
    $email = $_SESSION['email']; 
    $questionId = $_POST['questionId'];


    $insert = "INSERT INTO `answerList`(`answer`, `email`, `questionID`) VALUES ('$answ','$email','$questionId[value-3]')" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
 
    if (!$result) {
        echo "<script>alert('ERROR !!!!! '); location='faq.php';</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Successful Post'); location='faq.php'; </script>";
    }
    


}
```

Comment: i have error in this line <input type='hidden' name='questionId' value='<?php echo $value>'> Undefined variable: value how can i solve this error?

Comment: it's put in the <form method="POST">?

Comment: you have to declare variable $value (or how you want to call it). Just call $value and give it the questionID

Comment: you have to add the input inside the form